# Why did Codd, et al. prohibit intermediate scalars in SELECT - and how would they have recommended avoiding syntactic repetition?

Tags: query, subquery, syntax

(I'm asking this because [I was reviewing this older question I asked](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/196292/do-any-sql-dialects-permit-the-logical-sequence-of-select-clauses) and because I'm currently writing some queries and getting annoyed at how much I need to repeat myself).

In ISO-compliant SQL implementations, expressions and computed-columns in a `SELECT` clause cannot be referenced by other expressions in the same query (i.e. not in other expressions in the same `SELECT`, nor the same query's `WHERE`, `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses). The result is that queries that perform simple text-processing operations end-up unnecessarily verbose.

Consider a query that returns the first-substring delimited by angle-brackets `'<text goes here>'` without causing runtime errors if the text is `'> like this <'` or `'this>'`:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN
            CHARINDEX( '<', textBlob ) > 0 AND CHARINDEX( '>', textBlob, CHARINDEX( '<', textBlob ) > CHARINDEX( '<', textBlob ) )
            THEN 
                SUBSTRING(
                    textBlob,
                    /*start:*/ CHARINDEX( '<', textBlob ),
                    /*length:*/ CHARINDEX( '>', textBlob, CHARINDEX( '<', textBlob ) ) - CHARINDEX( '<', textBlob )
                ) AS angleBracketText
    END
FROM
    table
-- Alternatively, move the CASE WHEN expression to the WHERE clause.
```

The only alternative which avoids any repetition of scalar function call-sites is to use derived-table inner-queries - which introduces repetition of column projections (which isn't as bad as scalar function repetition, but still tedious):

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING( textBlob, openIdx, closeIdx - openIdx ) AS angleBracketText
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            textBlob,
            openIdx,
            closeIdx
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    textBlob,
                    openIdx,
                    CHARINDEX( '>', textBlob, openIdx ) AS closeIdx
                FROM
                    (
                        SELECT
                            textBlob,
                            CHARINDEX( '<', textBlob ) AS openIdx
                        FROM
                            table
                    ) AS q1
                WHERE
                    openIdx >= 0
            ) AS q2
        WHERE
            closeIdx > openIdx
    ) AS q3
```

Did *Codd, et al.* really design SQL to be used like this? I know that they [intended for SQL to be a "natural language"](http://vldb.org/conf/2007/papers/demo/p1358-minock.pdf) (which was all the rage in the 1970s), which surely implies a degree of terseness and eliminating redundant logic (because natural-language has lots of self-references like "it", "this", "that", etc), so I doubt they really intended their language-rules to result in this kind of query being written...

So, at risk of asking an un-answerable question (as the original designers of SQL are *away from the keyboard* right now): Why did Codd, et al. prohibit intermediate scalars in SELECT - and how would they have recommended avoiding syntactic repetition like in the above queries?

---

#### Footnote:

<sub>(If I had my way (I wish...) I'd be able to express it like this...)</sub>

```
SELECT
    $openIdx  = CHARINDEX( '<', textBlob ),
    $closeIdx = CASE WHEN $openIdx >= 0 THEN CHARINDEX( '>', textBlob, $openIdx ) END,
    CASE WHEN $openIdx >= 0 AND $closeIdx >= 0 THEN
        SUBSTRING( textBlob, $openIdx, $closeIdx - $openIdx )
    END AS angleBracketText
FROM
    table
```

Comment: MySQL has [`user-defined variables`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mysql-user-defind-variables/#:~:text=Mysql%20also%20supports%20the%20concept,.%2C%20_%2C%20and%20%24.) which gets you some of that functionality - also, servers' (of all stripes) procedural extensions (e.g. PL/pgSQL, PL/SQL, T-SQL... &c.) can do what you require!

Comment: @Vérace Right - though with T-SQL and Oracle this would have to be changed into a Scalar UDF as only MySQL supports (in non-ISO-compliant-mode) using named expressions in a query (Oracle does have macros, but I don't know if they cover this use-case). But to be clear: I am not asking "how can I do this?" - my question is "Did the (original) designers of SQL *really* intend for conceptually simple queries to end-up this complicated? If not, then how should it be done?".